# when post comment on my blog post page goes blank

Tags: wordpress

When i try to post comment on my blog post page doesn't load. it shows blank white screen.

http://my09site.co.nf/blog/

Not even able to identify the error. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some plugins cause the white screen. Please try comment after deactivating all plugins. If it will work, check activating one by one plugins which help you to find which plugins cause an error. Contact plugins author to solve your issue one you find actual cause for error is plugins.

Answer (score 0):

it's error due to wrongly formatted code in comments.php.

Either you changed it, or upgraded wordpress or theme.

Comment: Yes i had made changes to upload flash file. What should i do now.                  As per the link below i had made changes.                                                           https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-upload-swf-files-to-wordpress-anymore

Comment: @Jazz what's upload flash file. either you are totally newbie trying to establish more than enough or you are totally confused . why are you taking about uploading flash and stuff when you are having error with comments stuff

Comment: Yes, i am totally new. Actually i was trying to upload a flash file in the Media and it was showing "you can't upload due to security reasons". Then i searched on google find this solution. After this i was able to upload the flash file. is this due to that only.

Comment: @Jazz no flash has nothing to do with your comments , neither allow flash upload if not necessary

Comment: Then what's the resolution now.